# Mirror images of knots and Kauffman and HOMFLY polynomial

Tags: knot-theory

Let $K$ is a knot and let $\bar{K}$ be the mirror image of $K$.

I want to confirm this relationships.

Let $f_K(t)$ be the Kauffman polynomial of $K$.  To get the mirror image we swap every right hand move with a left hand move and vice versa.  So every $t \to t^{-1}$ and $t^{-1}\to t$.  Thus $f_{\bar{K}}(t)=f_{K}(t^{-1})$.

A similar relationship exists with the HOMFLY polynomial: $P_{\bar{K}}(l,m)=P_{K}(-l,m)$. I am having problems establishing the HOMFLY relationship.  Could I get a push in the right direction for that one?

Comment: I think it's $l\to 1/l$, not $l\to -l$.